# Oracle function to select multiple rows in a single row not working

Tags: oracle, listagg

I am loading a file into a staging record using Application Engine. when ever there is blank in BU,Deptid etc... I have to capture what all columns are blank and update error text field with those values.

UPDATE SYSADM.PS_VI_EMP_TS SET ERR_TEXT = 
SELECT ERROR FROM (SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN BUSINESS_UNIT = ' ' THEN 'BUSINESS_UNIT IS NULL' ELSE ' ' END AS ERROR FROM SYSADM.PS_VI_EMP_TS WHERE USERID='JCOOPER' AND ACTION = 'E' AND PROCESS_INSTANCE = '7852429' 
UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN DEPTID = ' ' THEN 'DEPTID IS NULL' ELSE ' ' END AS ERROR FROM SYSADM.PS_VI_EMP_TS WHERE USERID='JCOOPER' AND ACTION = 'E' AND PROCESS_INSTANCE = '9852429' 
UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN PROJECT_ID =' ' THEN 'PROJECT_ID IS NULL' ELSE ' ' END AS ERROR FROM SYSADM.PS_VI_EMP_TS WHERE USERID='JCOOPER' AND ACTION = 'E' AND PROCESS_INSTANCE = '9852429' 
)) WHERE ERROR <> ' '
WHERE USERID='JCOOPER' AND ACTION = 'E' AND PROCESS_INSTANCE = '9852429'

The above script results as below.

### ERROR

BUSINESS_UNIT IS NULL
DEPTID IS NULL

I want the result as below.

### ERROR

BUSINESS_UNIT IS NULL,DEPTID IS NULL

I am using ListAgg function but facing errors as below.Any help would be great.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(BUSINESS_UNIT, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY USERID) 
FROM SYSADM.PS_VI_EMP_TS WHERE USERID='JCOOPER'
GROUP BY BUSINESS_UNIT
```

Facing the error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 47 Column: 43
```

Comment: seems fine from this end, I run essentially the same query on my end (against a junk table, but same sql you got there) .. works fine. Only thing I can think of is any special/hidden characters in there anywhere ?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? `LISTAGG` was introduced in 11gR2, see https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2

Comment: Also, your SQL statement looks buggy - filtering by user_id and also using the user_id in the `ORDER BY` clause will give you a random ordering, and putting `business_unit` both inside `LISTAGG` and inside your `GROUP BY`will only concatenate the same business_unit multiple times. What are you trying to achieve? [Edit]ing your question and adding sample input and expected output would help tremendously.

Comment: That error suggests a syntax error, but the query works for me in sqlfiddle. Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I would better put here what I am trying to achive.

Comment: I have updated my question with requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You overcomplicated things. You don't need two unions and `listagg` at all. Simple use concatenation of `case... when`, write your select like here:

```
select case business_unit when ' ' then 'BUSINESS_UNIT IS NULL; ' end ||
       case deptid        when ' ' then 'DEPTID IS NULL; '        end ||
       case project_id    when ' ' then 'PROJECT_ID IS NULL; '    end as error
  from ps_vi_emp_ts 
  where userid = 'JCOOPER' and action = 'E' and process_instance = '9852429'
```

**<sup>[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48d030/2)</sup>**

If your table has primary key then use it for update. Otherwise you can use `merge` with rowid. Or do it the way you did it if it worked for you, especially if there is only one row meeting criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ponder. This help me out.